# Scroll bars in NSTokenField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nstokenfield

Is it possible to get scroll bars on an NSTokenField when there are too many items to display?

I've tried embedding it in a scroll view but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSTokenField` is a subclass of `NSTextField`, which does not have scroll bars. It seems quite unlikely that `NSTokenField` would have scroll bars.

Answer (score 1):

You can get scroll bars in an NSTokenField by inserting the scroll view into the token field. You also have to do the resizing of the token field yourself. Also, make sure the wraps functionality of the token field is turned on.